# Flutter issue with circleavatar networkImage not changing

Tags: flutter-layout

I am facing a problem that when the image is uploaded to server then the image is not changing in drawer circle avatar.

And I am NetworkImage("url")

I have created it as a widget and also tried to change its state using set state but its not changing till I hot restart it. One thing I am thinking is that the Network image is somewhere stored in my device. If so then how to delete it and reload it.

Comment: Please include your code

Answer (score 0):

I finally find a solution. I have changed my server backend to change the imager url each time when the image is uploaded.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).